# Given $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, find $q$ and $r$ such that $x=qy+r$.

Tags: ring-theory, complex-numbers

> Find $q, r \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that:
>
> 1. $1 + 5i = (1 + 2i)q + r$ with $|r| < 2$,
> 2. $1 + 5i = (2i)q + r$ with $|r| < 2$.

My only train of thought is that $r = 1+0i$, $0+i$ or $0$.

Otherwise I'm quite lost.

Edit:
Is the 2nd part possible at all? I cant figure out anything that works.

Comment: What this is saying is to divide. Divide $1+5i$ by $1+2i$, and you'll get a [q]uotient and a [r]emainder.

Comment: You are correct that there are very few possible $r\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ with $|r|<2$; there are two more than you have written though.

Comment: oh of course +/- 1

Comment: @Kieran That was an aside though - mixedmath's comment is correct, you are being asked to do division with remainder.

Comment: @mixedmath 1+5i/1+2i is (11+3i)/5 , where do i get the quotient and remainder values?

Comment: all i can find is q=2, r=-1+1 then |r|=2

Answer (score 0):

Hint for (1). Show that the problem is equivalent to finding a lattice point $q$ that is within a distance of $2/\sqrt{5}$ from $(1 + 5i)/(1 + 2i)$.